# Asking for thoughts vs listing pros and cons

Tags: discussion, questions

I once asked the question "What are your thoughts on using python as a back-end language?" The question was taken down for being too opinion based. If I were to change the question to "What are the specific pros and cons of using python as a back-end language?" and evaluate whether or not I should use it for myself, would that make a better question? or would it still be flagged?

Comment: As opposed to using it as a front-end language?

Comment: Cf.https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-is-the-problem-with-pros-and-cons,  https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8110/97259 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124930/159251

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope - the question is still too broad.  There's nothing concrete or objective for us to weigh in on, so you're not going to elicit any definitive answer from a question asking this.

I've used Python as a backend for a project, and I've used Ruby as a backend for a project.  I've used Java as a backend for a project.  The reason these were chosen was all subjective and up to business requirements, and not *inherently* tied to any specific technical reason.

It'd be better for you to evaluate the pros and cons yourself.  There's heaps of reading material out there on the Internet about this kind of thing; we're simply not one of them.

Comment: This is an excellent answer on why "what is your opinion about..." type questions are not allowed at SO. Every newbie and a lot of veterans should read it.