# Want to ask a question, but is it off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for some guidance with off-topicness.

I've a specific question involving [activemq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activemq) and [apache-camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-camel) which is to do with the way I process messages. I've two fully working solutions, but I could do with understanding the pros/cons of each, and if there are any major 'gotchas' in my solution(s).

Would a question like this end up getting marked as 'off-topic/opinionated'?

I've see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362207/3788685) & [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377270/3788685) discussion but my question isn't some generic "could I do this..." or "what's the best way to..."

Any advice please folks?

If this is off-topic then what would be a valid way to try and get the guidance I'm looking for?

Edit:
Some folks has suggested that this might count as [Gorilla Vs Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) but *personally* I don't think it is. This is more right handed Gorilla vs Left handed as I've two fully working solutions and am not pitting them against each other in a fight

I've also had a suggestion that this may be suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) though I would need to brush up on what's acceptable over there as (without checking) this is more a 'solution review'.

At the moment going on meta votes it's even pegging between code-review & post my question and provide two answers and let the community vote/answer. The general feeling I'm getting from very high rep users so far is this question may well fall foul of flagging at the moment.

If it's not against any meta rules I'm happy to post the draft question here for further scrutiny.

Comment: By the description _"I could do with understanding the pros/cons of each, and if there are any major 'gotchas'"_, it would likely be too broad, due to being very open-ended. This [question that you linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377270/3788685) seems to apply here.

Comment: @E_net4 Hmmm. I *think* my question is specific enough to avoid that. As in I have two simple and describable solutions fully working and live, I'm just trying to work out if either of them leaves me open to crashing & burning in production environment. I'm happy to draft post the question here if it's of use and not against something on meta.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: It sounds to me like your question might be better suited for [codereview.se]

Comment: @RobertLongson - I personally don't see it as gorilla vs shark, as it's more left handed gorilla vs right handed. (or something like that) This is more I have two ways of doing the same thing with the same software/code. You can see my confusion hence I came here.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Interesting - I'd not really thought about that, having never ventured over there I wasn't sure if it would be valid there either. Its not really a code review more a solution review if you catch my drift? If that's valid there then I'll give it a go.

Comment: This question would entirely be opinion based, all the answers would be subjective and would need detailed analysis of your environment and goals. In fact they could probably only ever opinions. I think you really need to ask this in more a forum setting. or get some paid professional advice

Answer (score 28):

For better or worse, "better" and "worse" tend to be hot-button words that often trigger votes to close your question as "primarily opinion-based".

The trick, so to speak, is to formulate your question in a way that does not use those words, or any other similar trigger phrases (such as asking whether a library exists to do what you want, which is all but guaranteed to get your question closed as a "request for off-site resources").  Rather, **just ask how to solve the problem you have**, and rely on the answerers to provide (and upvote) the solutions they think are best.

In your case, since you happen to already have two solutions which you believe to be adequate, one option might be to also post both as **answers to your own question**, and rely on voters to indicate which of them (if either) is the best solution.  If your solutions have any obvious drawbacks, you will likely receive comments pointing them out, and possibly answers suggesting better alternatives, just because that's what people here normally do when they see an answer with issues.

Just remember to also briefly note in your question that you've posted some self-answers below, and would welcome any feedback on them or any alternative solutions.  Otherwise, you may get downvotes and comments asking you what you've tried from users who haven't noticed that some of the answers below are also from you.  (Admittedly, the UI could make that more obvious.  It's pretty easy to spot *if* you scroll down *and* happen to look at the user cards on the answers, but not everybody does that every time.)

(Of course, all of the above assumes that your question *can* be formulated in a way that is on-topic here.  If it e.g. requires "detailed analysis of your environment and goals" to answer, as suggested in one of the comments above, and if such information cannot be concisely included in your question, then it may not be suitable for Stack Overflow in the first place.  Basically, a good SO question should be such that it can be answered by someone familiar with the subject — but who does not work with you and doesn't have access to your codebase and servers — based *only* on the information in the question.)

Comment: I never liked self-answer questions, but you've made a good use case for it.

Comment: @ilmari I'm happy to post a flavour of the actual question here if it's of help (and not against a meta rule) - I've also had the suggestion of code review, both of these carry the same score as I type this reply.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes the only wrong is when a good answer does not get posted to Stack Overflow due to self-imposed barriers.

Comment: Asking the question and answering it with different answers is my go to way. Example: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/52533564/1248177](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52533564/1248177)

Answer (score 8):

While I agree with Ilmari about how to approach asking your question here, I'd like to reinforce Madara's suggestion: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Questions about **how to improve working code** are decidedly on-topic there, and such open-ended questions as yours are given weight in the review.

Several bits in your question hint at Code Review qualification, so let's approach from that direction:

- > I've a specific question involving activemq and apache-camel which is to do with the way I process messages.

Okay so far for either Stack Overflow or Code Review.

- > I've two fully working solutions

Code Reviewers like code that works already. ;-)

- > but I could do with understanding the pros/cons of each

This sounds like you need eyes to analyze your two solutions from a design aspect.

- > and if there are any major 'gotchas' in my solution(s).

And this sounds like you are looking for general help improving your code quality.

I see nothing that *disqualifies* you from posting on CR and plenty that encourages it, while you've had to reach out on Meta to to see if your question is qualified on SO at all. This is not critique of you, but rather a suggestion that you spread your wings a bit and try out another site on the SE network. My solo venture into CR was decidedly helpful and taught me a great deal (for what my anecdotal evidence is worth).

Perhaps if after posting on CR you are left unsatisfied, you could narrow the breadth of your question from the feedback received on CR, then come back to SO with a more concise question (possibly even self-answered!).

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look over there later in the week and have a read through the help pages. I presume I'd just need to provide my code from my `activemq.xml` and `camel.xml` config files along with a suitable description of the project. One version of this has an external parser dependency; would I need to include that as well? This isn't really something someone can spin up and test as the upstream messaging provider is external and requires access. I'm encouraged to note even a mod thinks this qualifies for CR :) - every day is a school day.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to make sure that both versions run and work as expected, then post each one of them (complete code) at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Two separate questions each asking for a code review. You don't have to be specific unless you want to, then it is ok to ask that the review focus on certain aspects such as performance, program design, portability etc.

Comment: We do have the [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) tag on Code Review, so posting both solutions in one question should be fine (as long as both work).

Comment: @Graipher Yeah but it will be a bit messy, I think 2 separate questions is better. They can link to each other if needed.

Comment: @Lundin: It will depend on the actual question(s). If both solutions are short enough, posting them together might be fine, otherwise you are probably right.